# problem with rsync. forgot the ending dot and can't find beackupfiles now

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am new with linux and tried to backu my files doing this:

```
rsync -arvu /home /etc /opt /var
```

I was in the desired directory (on an external hard-disk drive) and logged in as su.
but no files where in my directory after that. And Ubuntu told me that my hard-dsik is full ... absolutely full... 0 Bytes left.

then I did (with the dot in the end) this:

```
rsync -arvu /home /etc /opt /var .
```

and all worked fine... **BUT**

my hard space (not the external one) is absolutely full now.

**WHERE did rsync put the files of the first try? how can I remove them? ... HEELP! :-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last argument is the destination. So your first command copied `/home/SOMETHING` to `/var/home/SOMETHING`, and so on.¹ Most Ubuntu systems don't have a `/var/home`, a `/var/etc` or a `/var/opt`, so you should be fine just deleting those directories.